# Is there anything inherently wrong with dynamic downcasting in C++?

Tags: c++

I've heard it said several times that if you need to dynamically downcast then there may be something wrong with the design. I see it as a similar mechanism to COMs queryinterface, querying an object at run-time to see what interfaces it supports and then invoking the appropriate method(s) accordingly.

Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: It's like `goto`: often maligned, usually misused, occasionally the right tool for the job.

Comment: Pretty disappointed you didn't go down the *`inherit`ly wrong* pun path, here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing *inherently* wrong with it, and sometimes it's appropriate, but it's often poor design to write code that makes decisions based on the dynamic type of an object.  If you have something like this:

```
void foo(Base const *base) {
  Derived1 const *derived1 = dynamic_cast<Derived1 const *>(base);
  if (derived1) {
    // Do stuff
  }

  Derived2 const *derived2 = dynamic_cast<Derived2 const *>(base);
  if (derived2) {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

you'd probably be better off putting that functionality *into* the derived classes as a virtual function, and letting the language's built-in dynamic dispatch take care of figuring out which code to run.  That way, if you add a `Derived3` later, you don't have to find all the places in your code where you're checking for `Derived` or `Derived2`, and add a check for `Derived3` as well.  Just implement the virtual function in `Derived3` and all the existing virtual function calls will work.

Comment: I guess I'm looking at it from an interface programming  point of view, where you don't have 1 interface that does everything, but instead multiple interfaces that add functionality to an object as is needed. example perhaps would be to make some objects in a collection serialisable whilst others not. So I would want to test for the serialisable interface. Or even a collection of controls which would have a common base class but whose functionality diverges enough to require additional functionality as you go down the hierarchy.

Comment: Casting to "mix-in" interfaces like serializable makes more sense; that's not really downcasting within a hierarchy.  In a hierarchy of UI control classes, where you want to check whether a particular control supports a certain capability, you could use interfaces for each capability (e.g. clickable, resizable), since those are also mix-ins, not part of the hierarchy.  The difference between this and my example above is that you're not putting behavior outside of the class based on a downcast; the behavior is implemented in the class, and you're just checking whether you can call it.

Comment: The above however is a good option if it only applies to one or two objects in the hierarchy at one particular point in the code. It is very suspect to be adding functions at the root of the hierarchy just to satisfy one piece of code for a few items in that hiearchy. Trying to cram everything into the base of the hiearchy leads to some aweful code.

Answer (score 3):

As with many other features of programming languages, there are appropriate uses (COM might be one such case), but in most cases it indicates that you have created a type hierarchy that is not rich enough for your needs (does not offer all the operations you need) or that you are forcing the inheritance relationship on types that are not really related (and thus have different sets of operations).

Note that this is also the case of the COM interface, where besides the basic publishing of what interfaces are supported, the objects share very little to nothing. But in that particular case, the binding of unrelated types in a hierarchy is a need of the particular interface defined in the system.